# Unexpected "en" (in Harry Potter à l'école des sorciers)

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

> Dans son bureau du huitième étage, Mr Dursley s'asseyait toujours dos
>   à la fenêtre. **S'il en avait été autrement**, il aurait sans doute eu un
>   peu plus de mal que d'habitude à se concentrer sur ses perceuses, ce
>   matin-là.

What is “en” supposed to mean in this context? How to properly translate this sentence?

Comment: This is a formal form of "Si cela n'avait pas été le cas".

Answer (score 6):

The word "en" is not always a preposition, in this case it refers to the situation, described in the previous sentence ("...s'asseyait toujours dos à la fenêtre.").

An easier and more visual way to figure this is to imagine what the sentence would look like without this word : "S'il avait été autrement ...", it would be a little confusing because "il" could refer to "Mr Dursley".

Hope I helped you with that ;)

You can find more information about "en" and its different use cases on this [page](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-105600.php)

Answer (score 0):

This could be translated as, *"if it hadn't been so"* or *"if this hadn't been the case"*. Thus, as Martin explains, **"en"** refers to the situation being described.